# orthogonal group what does it represent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, intuition, characters

> Let $A$ be an finite abelian group and $B$ be a subgroup of $A$. Then we defined the orthogonal of $B$ : 
>   $$B^{\perp} = \{f:(A,+) \to (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},+) \mid \forall b \in B ,f(b) = 0 \}$$

I understand the definition, but I don't understand what it really represents. In linear algebra, the orthogonal of a sub-vector space has a very nice geometric meaning. Here I don't understand what it represents and why it's useful?

Hence here I am really seeking for intuition. For example, if I take famous groups like the dihedral group of the symmetric group and take a subgroup of one of these group. Then what the orthogonal will represent?

I we think of a group as a set of transformations that can act on some set $X$ maybe the orthogonal has a more geometric meaning?

Finally, why do we take morphism that go to the group : $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ ? I know this has a link with representation theory but isn't there a simple explanation to take this group ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can't really take the dihedral or symmetric groups, as this is about abelian groups.

Here's an interesting analogy : for a vector space $V$, you have a dual vector space $V^*:= \hom(V,k)$, and if $W\leq V$ is a subvector space, then $W^\bot\leq V^*$ is a subvector space. Here, for an abelian group $A$ you have a dual abelian group $\check{A} := \hom (A, \mathbb{Q/Z})$, and given $B\leq A$ a subgroup you have $B^\bot \leq \check{A}$.

Essentially it will be as useful as $V^*,W^\bot$ are in the context of vector spaces.

The reason why $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is that, just as $k$ is a cogenerator in the category of vector spaces, $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is one in the category of abelian groups. What does it mean ? Here, essentially, it reduces to the fact that given $x\in A\setminus\{0\}$, there is a map $A\to \mathbb{Q/Z}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$, this is because $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is *injective*, i.e. given a subgroup $B\leq A$ and a map $f:B\to \mathbb{Q/Z}$, there is a map $g:A\to \mathbb{Q/Z}$ extending $f$.

Then for $x\neq 0 \in A$, either $x$ has a finite order $n$, in which case $x\mapsto \frac{1}{n}$ mod $\mathbb{Z}$ gives a map $\langle x\rangle \to \mathbb{Q/Z}$ which sends $x$ to something nonzero; either $x$ has infinite order, in which case you can send it to anything nonzero in $\mathbb{Q/Z}$; in either case there is a nonzero $f:\langle x\rangle \to \mathbb{Q/Z}$, which can then be extended to $A$.

So $\check{A}$ separates points of $A$, and so plays a similar role to $V^*$ in the context of $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are completely right for the symmetric and dihedral group, that was a stupid question on my part. I think I understand better why we use the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Nevertheless, I don't understand how it gives a geometric/intuition about the orthogonal of a group. I already knew your analogy, but I don't understand how it helps understanding the orthogonal of a subgroup. Also I don't understand your last sentence : "... separates points of $A$". What separates points means and how did you conlude that ? (so there is an intuition about the dual?)

Comment: It doesn't really give geometric intuition, unless you already have some concerning the orthogonal of a subvector space. If you do, then you can think of it as being similar, so it does give some geometric insight. $\check{A}$ separates points of $A$ means if $x\neq y$, then there is some $f\in\check{A}$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$, and it follows directly from what I mentioned.

Comment: +1Thank you. The problem is that for me the orthogonal of a subvector space $W$ is:$\{x \in V \mid B(x,y) = 0 \forall y \in W\}$ where $B$ is a bilinear form hence it's composed of vectors not of functions whereas the orthogonal of a subgroup is a set of functions. Hence for me the orthogonal of a s.v.s $W$ is really just the space orthogonal to $W$ in $V$, so geometricaly this is very intuitive. For the orthogonal of a group it doesn't seem like I can relate the element of $B^\perp$ with the one of $B$ since there are different (one are morphisms whereas in $B$ we just have element of a g $G$

Comment: That's a version of the orthogonal when you are given a bilinear form $B$. Similarly if you were given a bilinear map $A\times A\to \mathbb{Q/Z}$, you could define the orthogonal subgroup as a subgroup of $A$. But for a general vector space $V$, with no given bilinear form, the orthogonal is indeed a subvector space of $V^*$. To relate the two, note that if you are given a bilinear form $B$, you have a clear map $V\to V^*$ (analogously $A\to \check{A}$) defined by $j: x\mapsto (y\mapsto B(x,y))$, and then the orthogonal subvector space of $W\leq V$ is $j^{-1}(W^\bot)$, where $W^\bot\leq V^*$

Comment: (and similarly $j^{-1}(B^\bot)$, where $B^\bot \leq \check{A}$). Here in some sense it's more general, it's a "universal" orthogonal because you can find any orthogonal defined by a bilinear form thanks to it

Comment: Great thank you, it makes much more sense to me now. So actually now to really get a good intuition, I should ask myself what an inner product means on the dual group. In a vector space, the euclidian inner product is a projection. in the dual group the inner product is between two characters, it seems much harder to see what information it gives. For example if two characters are orthogonal what does it mean ? Nevertheless I accept your answer since you answered all the questions of my post.